# zlib and lzma go unresponsive when decompressing - python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, zlib, lzma

When I compress a 31kb string using the lzma module or the zlib module and decompress it, python goes unresponsive and takes up around 50% of my cpu. The modules work with smaller strings.

Here is my code:

```
import zlib

open_file = open('big_file.txt','r')

text = open_file.read()

compressed = zlib.compress(text.encode('UTF-8'))
print(compressed)


decompressed = zlib.decompress(bytes(compressed))
print(str(decompressed))
```

Edit:

Cpu: Intel Core 2 Extreme X7900 @ 2.8ghz

Ram: 3gb DDR 2

Os: Windows 10 64bit (admin rights)

Python Version: 3.4.3 32bit

Comment: Does the compression ever end? Do you have 2 cores?

Comment: I don't know if it ever ended because I forced closed the program. Yes, I have 2 cores.

Comment: Can you add some information about what platform you are running on? OS, CPU real machine or virtual, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to take that long on Python 3. Note that I have read the text as bytes, and have left out some encoding/str steps that are not necessary on Python 3.

Tests done on an Intel Core 2 Q9300 running at 2.5 GHz. Python 3.4.3 (64-bit) compiled with Clang 3.4.1 on FreeBSD 10.2 AMD64.

```
In [1]: import zlib

In [2]: with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as datafile:
    btext = datafile.read()
   ...:     

In [3]: len(btext)
Out[3]: 23931

In [4]: type(btext)
Out[4]: bytes
```

This text is around 23 kiB, and is already in the form of `bytes`, so it doesn't need encoding.

```
In [5]: compressed = zlib.compress(btext)

In [6]: %timeit zlib.compress(btext)
1000 loops, best of 3: 735 µs per loop

In [7]: len(compressed)
Out[7]: 4787

In [8]: type(compressed)
Out[8]: bytes

In [9]: uncompressed = zlib.decompress(compressed)

In [10]: %timeit zlib.decompress(compressed)
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop
```

Both compression and decompression are measured in microseconds. That's hardly noticable.

Replicating your code more precisely gives approximately the same result:

```
In [1]: import zlib

In [2]: with open('foo.txt') as datafile:
    text = datafile.read()
   ...:     

In [3]: %timeit zlib.compress(text.encode('UTF-8'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 767 µs per loop

In [4]: compressed =  zlib.compress(text.encode('UTF-8'))

In [5]: type(compressed)
Out[5]: bytes

In [6]: %timeit zlib.decompress(bytes(compressed))
10000 loops, best of 3: 121 µs per loop
```

The problem seems to be in your environment. Possibilities are;

- Not enough memory leading to swapping.
- User limits set too low on UNIX-like operating systems.
- Slow CPU.

You'd have to supply some more information about your environment.

Comment: So, what's your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is because in the last line `str(decompressed)`, you are building a 'readable' representation of a binary string. This process is slow and memory hungry.

An example:

```
>>> b = bytes(range(256))
>>> len(b)
256
>>> len(str(b))
738
>>>
```

Try this with big strings.